# delete multiple rows from a table in SQLI with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to delete all the rows from table called `memo` that the user is the same user. The text is the same text and the color is the same color:

This is what I have

```
$query = "DELETE FROM memo WHERE (`username`='$user',`text`='$text',`color`='$color')";
```

and I get this result:

> Operand should contain 1 column(s) 
>   What am I doing wrong?

SOLVED:

Should have used `AND` instead

```
$query = "DELETE FROM memo WHERE (`username`='$user' AND `text`='$text' AND `color`='$color')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `AND` clause between where conditions:

```
 $query = "DELETE FROM memo WHERE `username`='$user' AND `text`='$text' AND `color`='$color'";
```